# How can I use Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate a generic type as part of a using block?

Tags: c#, using, activator

What I'd like to achieve is to convert the following method to something more generic:

```
    private Task<TestResult> SpecificServiceWarmUp(string serviceEndPoint)
    {
        return Task<TestResult>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            using (var service = new MySpecificClient(serviceEndPoint))
            {
                // do some stuff with specific client
            }
        });
    }
```

A more generic version would look like:

```
    private Task<TestResult> GenericServiceWarmUp<TService>(string serviceEndPoint)
    {
        return Task<TestResult>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            using (/* instance of TService */)
            {
                // do some stuff with generic client
            }
        });
    }
```

What I don't know is how to tell the `using` block to use `Activator` to create the instance of the generic type. Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to use `Activator`? I would rather put a `new()` constraint on `TService`.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev You can have `new()`, but not `new(string)`, which was desired here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a [constraint on your generic type parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) like that:

```
private Task<TestResult> GenericServiceWarmUp<TService>()
where TService : IDisposable
{
    return Task<TestResult>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (var service = 
            (TService)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TService), serviceEndPoint))
        {
            // do some stuff with generic client
        }
    });
}
```

Otherwise if your service has **no constructor parameter** you don't need to use `Activator.CreateInstance`, there is a **`new()` constraint**:

```
private Task<TestResult> GenericServiceWarmUp<TService>(string serviceEndPoint)
where TService : IDisposable, new()
{
    return Task<TestResult>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {

        using (var service = new TService())
        {
            // do some stuff with generic client
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: One thing: that overload of `Activator.CreateInstance` returns `object`, so you should cast to `TService`.

Comment: I've added the cast in my answer